# how to remove different kinds of strings in txt file using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file who contains songs list and their path. I want to remove the path so I'll only have the songs list row by row

```
D:\MUSIC\MAIN MUSIC\1980's\1980's - Easy\Chaka Kahn - Ain't Nobody.mp3
D:\MUSIC\MAIN MUSIC\1990's\1990's - Easy\Lisa Stansfield - All Around The World.mp3
```

I want to remove everything but the song and artist names

Comment: What did you tried as code until now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %A in ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\New Text Document.txt") Do Echo %~nA
```

See `For /?` for Help.